# weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

When i deploy my WAR in Weblogic 10.3.6 it runs but in weblogic 10.3.0 it throws this:

> Unable to load descriptor 
>   D:\bea103\user_projects\domains\SRVWinplex\Deployments\WinplexAdmin.war/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml
>   of module WinplexAdmin.war. The error is
>   weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed at
>   weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:152)
>   at
>   weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:306)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWeblogicWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:170)

It's a problem with the weblogic.xml i guess. This is my weblogic.xml(Without basic tags) :

> ```
> <jsp-descriptor>
>     <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
>     <debug>true</debug>
> </jsp-descriptor>
> <context-root>/WinplexAdmin</context-root>
> <library-ref>
>     <library-name>jsf</library-name>
>     <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
>     <implementation-version>1.0.0.0_2-0-2</implementation-version>
> </library-ref>
> <container-descriptor>
>     <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
> </container-descriptor>
> ```

What can be the problem here ?

Comment: All this problems is about xml initial tags, be careful with your version of weblogic and tags o your XML, try to find a example to your version and use them,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I was compiling with a newer weblogic.jar
I mean: I had Weblogic 10.3.6 attached to NetBeans, so it was a different weblogic.xml.

A correct weblogic.xml for Weblogic 10.3.0 is like this:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
```

You can see "http://www.bea.com/" in the xml while a weblogic.xml for Weblogic 11g and etc. has links with "java" or "sun" in it.

I just downloaded Weblogic 10.3.0, attached it to NetBeans, change the server for the project from Weblogic 10.3.6 to 10.3.0 and then re-compile.

Or... the easy way is just replacing the weblogic.xml code for the one i pasted here and compile.

I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sun XML Parser and not the default Weblogic XML parser this is what happening:

The problem is that the Sun parser fail to parse the web.xml of the apps if in this element:

```
<web-app version="2.5" metadata-complete="true" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

xmlns attribute is after  xmlns:xsi attribute.

xmlns attribute must be before xmlns:xsi attribute!

Took me very long time to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is not for you then you can use below one

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried with the solutions below and still not working, it may due to version mismatches in JavaVersion, try

1. Click on Windows
2. Click on Preferences.
3. Click on Java->Compiler. Check whether it is matching with the version you use in the application. Change the compiler compliance level if not matched