# how to deploy war file on weblogic 12c

Tags: deployment, weblogic

few days ago my boss told to deploy our project war file on weblogic12c and I did it but weblogic gave me this two error and I don't what should I do :

[all I see is about these error and next key stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI9h7.jpg)

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<web-app version="3.0" id="WebApp_ID" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<display-name>JournalDev-PrimefacesWebApplication</display-name>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>

<param-value>Production</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>

<param-value>ultima-#{guestPreferences.theme}</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>

<param-value>true</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/primefaces-ultima.taglib.xml</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>

<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>

<param-value>client</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>

<param-value>resources.application</param-value>

</context-param>


-<listener>

<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>

</listener>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>

<param-value>false</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>

<param-value>0</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>

<param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-beans.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-navigations.xml</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/config/applicationContext-*.xml,**/applicationContext-*.xml </param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>

<param-value>en</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>datasource</param-name>

<param-value>news_DS</param-value>

</context-param>


-<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>user/body.xhtml</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>


-<session-config>

<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>

</session-config>


-<filter>

<filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter>

<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>


-<init-param>

<param-name>encoding</param-name>

<param-value>UTF-8</param-value>

</init-param>


-<init-param>

<param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>

<param-value>true</param-value>

</init-param>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter>

<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>


-<init-param>

<description> Set the size limit for uploaded files. Format: 10 - 10 bytes 10k - 10 KB 10m - 10 MB 1g - 1 GB </description>

<param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>

<param-value>100m</param-value>

</init-param>


-<init-param>

<description> Set the threshold size - files below this limit are stored in memory, files above this limit are stored on disk. Format: 10 - 10 bytes 10k - 10 KB 10m - 10 MB 1g - 1 GB </description>

<param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>

<param-value>100k</param-value>

</init-param>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter>

<filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.nspl.access.AccessFilter</filter-class>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>

<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>

<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>

<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>

<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>picServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.PicServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>picServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/picServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>Select</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.Select</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>Select</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/Select</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.Index</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/Index</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>AttachmentServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.AttachmentServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>AttachmentServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/AttachmentServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>picPersonServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.PicPersonServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>picPersonServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/picPersonServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>baseInfoACMServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.BaseInfoACMServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>baseInfoACMServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/baseInfoACMServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>operationServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.OperationServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>operationServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/operationServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>bulletinServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.BulletinServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>bulletinServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/bulletinServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>reportsServlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.nspl.access.ReportsServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>reportsServlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/reportsServlet</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<servlet>

<servlet-name>Kaptcha</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>com.google.code.kaptcha.servlet.KaptchaServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>


-<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>Kaptcha</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/kaptcha.jpg</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>


-<listener>

<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

</listener>


-<listener>

<listener-class>org.nspl.access.SessionListener</listener-class>

</listener>


-<listener>

<listener-class> org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener </listener-class>

</listener>


-<listener>

<listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener </listener-class>

</listener>


-<context-param>

<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>

<param-value>false</param-value>

</context-param>


-<context-param>

<param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>

<param-value>false</param-value>

</context-param>


-<listener>

<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>

</listener>


-<filter>

<filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>

<filter-class>org.primefaces.ultima.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

</filter>


-<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>

<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

</filter-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>ttf</extension>

<mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>woff</extension>

<mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>woff2</extension>

<mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>eot</extension>

<mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>eot?#iefix</extension>

<mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg#exosemibold</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg#exobolditalic</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg#exomedium</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg#exoregular</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>


-<mime-mapping>

<extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>

<mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>

</mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my admin server log : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4URKdA128Y5WURXT1lnby13blE

I google it and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823016/weblogic-descriptor-descriptorexception-unmarshaller-failed) some solution it's about web.xml file but I don't don't understand what should i do ?

Comment: Please add complete error messages and log files snipets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for posting the admin server log. There is a long stack trace error in your server log that states:

```
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: **Bean already exists**: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.FilterMappingBeanImpl@f5a45ff9(/FilterMappings[[CompoundKey: **hibernateFilter**[CompoundKey: ][CompoundKey: *.xhtml]]])".
```

This can happen sometimes particularly when you're using WebLogic's autodeploy feature.  I've made an assumption here that you're deploying to a single server (Admin Server) in DEVELOPMENT mode using the autodeploy feature.

I would recommend the following:

1. In the admin console, delete the deployment, even if it is marked FAILED. If you get an error trying to delete it, then see below.
2. Shutdown all running WebLogic servers
3. Delete the contents of the auto deploy directory (if you're using autodeploy, which is what it looks like)
4. Delete the contents of
   /home/sadr/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp
5. If you were unable to delete the deployment via the admin console, you will have to remove the deployment from your domain's config.xml:
   /home/sadr/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/config/config.xml
   (make a backup before you edit)
6. Restart the admin server
7. Redeploy the WAR file

On a personal note, I'm not a fan of autodeploy unless you're doing the actual development on your own workstation. And even then, you would use JDeveloper to integrate with WebLogic in a local dev environment.  If you are working in more of an integration type environment, then I would recommend not using the autodeploy feature - which can be unrealiable at times.